# Values between range in javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array sorted in ascending order in java script which contains dates in milliseconds.

```
// Sample data; This may grow upto 1k or 2k
var dates = [1333391400000,1335292200000,1335810600000,1336329000000,1336933800000,1337020200000,
1337193000000,1337538600000,1337625000000,1337797800000,1338316200000,1338921000000,
1339093800000,1339439400000,1340303400000,1341772200000,1342463400000,1343068200000];
```

I don't have start and end index. I have values. I need to get all dates between 2 dates (Min and Max) from the java script array. I am getting this array from Java through JSON.

Here is the method to get dates between min and max:

```
function getDatesBetweenRange(min,max){
    var subArray = [];
    var value, jCntr=0;
    for(var iCntr=0;iCntr<dates.length;iCntr++){
         value = dates[iCntr];
         if(value>max)
             break;
         if(value >=min && value <=max){
             subArray[jCntr++]= value;
         }
    }
    return subArray;
}
```

As array is in ascending sorted order; I am breaking loop if I get max value than the provided max value in the argument.

Is there any other efficient way to get values from Java Script array ?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp

Comment: @Roset: I don't have start and end index. I have values

Comment: The only thing I can think of is perhaps to do a quick sample of the array (mid, quartiles etc.) to see if you can start your search later. Won't add a huge amount of computational effort, but could save you looking through some of the elements (could be significant if the array is large).

Comment: Not from an array but you could use a more suitable data structure such as a [range tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_tree).

Comment: @Esailija: I have a sorted array in ascending order and I think its not best to use Range Trees for it.

Comment: If you have just 2k values in that array and don't query them to often, than no optimization is likely to be required. If you do query them often, on the other hand, than a different data structure would give better results than searching the array every time. If that is not an option (which I find unlikely), try binary search (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm).

Comment: Binary search for both start and end + `splice` is probably fastest.

Comment: [only that fiddle for experiments](http://jsfiddle.net/EJsmy/)

Comment: The start and end don't have to be in the array, so binary search cannot be used

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov you're probably right. Asymptotically it's hard to get beyond O(log(n)) here, so binary search would be ok.

Comment: @Esailija it can, if you implement it properly.

Comment: @Qnan that's just irrelevant. It searches for exact values, how is the implementation going to change that?

Comment: @Esailija, then simply use other final condition instead of equality.

Comment: @Esailija binary search can identify the smallest element larger than a given value and the largest element smaller than a given value. Do you deny that?..

Comment: @Qnan I deny the usefulness of binary search in searching for a value in array that doesn't have the value, yes.

Comment: @Esailija well, you're wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a semi binary filter method that seems [more efficient](http://jsperf.com/filterarray) (at least in my browsers - Chrome, Firefox, IE9)

```
function filterBinary(arr,min,max){
 var len   = arr.length
    ,up    = -1
    ,down  = len
    ,rrange= []
    ,mid   = Math.floor(len/2) 
 ;
 while (up++<mid && down-->mid){
    if (arr[up]>=max || arr[down]<=min){break;}
    if (arr[up]>=min){
      rrange.push(arr[up]);
    }
    if (arr[down]<=max){
      rrange.push(arr[down]);
    }
 }
 return rrange;   
}
```

Comment: this could actually be slightly more efficient, but I understand Array.filter isn't available in some browsers

Comment: Notice that the middle value is outputted twice, e.g. `filterBinary([0,1,2], 0, 2) == [0, 2, 1, 1]`. Also, this is not a binary search, so you should rename the method :-)

Answer (score 3):

You might use [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) to get the indizes, then use [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice):

```
Array.prototype.sliceRange = function(min, max) {
    if (min > max) return this.sliceRange(max, min);
    var l = 0,
        r = this.length;
    // find an element at index m that is in range
    rough: {
        while (l < r) {
            var m = Math.floor(l + (r - l) / 2);
            if (this[m] < min)
                l = m + 1;
            else if (this[m] > max)
                r = m;
            else
                break rough;
        }
        // l == r: none was found
        return [];
    }
    var lr = m, // right boundary for left search
        rl = m; // left boundary for right search
    // get first position of items in range (l == lr)
    while (l < lr) {
        m = Math.floor(l + (lr - l) / 2);
        if (this[m] < min)
            l = m + 1;
        else
            lr = m;
    }
    // get last position of items in range (r == rl)
    while (rl < r) {
        m = Math.floor(rl + (r - rl) / 2);
        if (this[m] > max)
            r = m;
        else
            rl = m + 1;
    }
    // return the items in range
    return this.slice(l, r);
}
```

([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WHg9t/2/))

---

Yet, @Qnan's approach to do only one and a half searches (instead of my three half searches) is more straightforward and should not suffer any disadvantages. I only would use loops that result in exact indices:

```
Array.prototype.sliceRange = function(min, max) {
    if (min > max) return this.sliceRange(max, min);
    var l = 0,
        c = this.length,
        r = c;
    // get first position of items in range (l == c)
    while (l < c) {
        var m = Math.floor(l + (c - l) / 2);
        if (this[m] < min)
            l = m + 1;
        else
            c = m;
    }
    // get last position of items in range (c == r)
    while (c < r) {
        var m = Math.floor(c + (r - c) / 2);
        if (this[m] > max)
            r = m;
        else
            c = m + 1;
    }
    // return the items in range
    return this.slice(l, r);
}
```

Comment: The `min` and `max` are not in the array necessarily, so they would return -1. A binary search would also return `-1` but faster

Comment: @Esailija: By binary search I mean a binary algorithm to return the indices of the elements that are in the range, not to search for the min/max values themselves. Still working on the code :-)

Comment: You still cannot use `slice`, as you have to linearly iterate the range and check all of them. If you remove that linear iteration from `Qnan`'s answer, it won't work. So no matter how you put it, you cannot use binary search to get the indices and slice.

Comment: I can't get your latest edit to work :-P Getting empty array as result no matter what I put in. `[0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 25, 243, 424].sliceRange(1,3)
//[]`

Comment: Oh, I can :-) The last search(es) to get upper and lower bounds do not need to be linear. Sorry for the confusion with all the edits

Comment: Heh, glad to see you got it working now. There was an infinite loop earlier as well.

Comment: Yes, that was because the last middle pointer needs to be computed with `ceil` instead of `floor`

Comment: @Bergi your bottom code doesn't seem to work correctly. `var a = [-1,2,3,3,3,6,6,6,99,100,100,101];
a.sliceRange(96,98);
//[99]` http://jsfiddle.net/sjbwN/

Comment: @Esailija because at the bottom you have `r+1`

Answer (score 2):

The problem with trying to optimize the loop like this (breaking out of the sorted list after max is reached) is that you are doing a check each time you iterate. Its faster in some cases to just iterate through the entire list. Particularly when the values you are searching for are at the end of the list (e.g. more recent dates)

But, if it makes a difference you need a binary search algorithm. Lodash has a function that uses a binary search to retrieve the index where a value would be inserted. Combine this with slice and the result should be optimal.

**Using [Lodash][1]**

```
// sliced :  get all values between+including min-max from sorted array of numbers
// @param array sorted timestamps
// @param min timestamp minimum
// @param max timestamp maximum
function sliced(array,min,max){
    return array.slice(_.sortedIndex(array, min),_.sortedIndex(array, max)+1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's roughly what the binary search would look like in this case

```
var dates = [1333391400000,1335292200000,1335810600000,1336329000000,1336933800000,1337020200000,
1337193000000,1337538600000,1337625000000,1337797800000,1338316200000,1338921000000,
1339093800000,1339439400000,1340303400000,1341772200000,1342463400000,1343068200000];

function getDatesBetweenRange(min, max) {
    var subArray = [];
    var value, iCntr;
    var start, end;

    var low = 0, high = dates.length - 1;
    while (high - low > 1) {
        centre = Math.floor((high + low) / 2);
        if (dates[centre] < min)
            low = centre;
        else 
            high = centre;
    }
    start = low;
    high = dates.length - 1
    while (high - low > 1) {
        centre = Math.floor((high + low) / 2);
        if (dates[centre] > max)
            high = centre;
        else 
            low = centre;
    }
    end = high;

    for (var i = start; i < end; i++) {
        value = dates[i];
        if (value < min) {
            continue;
        }
        if (value > max) {
            break;
        }
        subArray.push(value);
    }
    return subArray;
}

console.log(getDatesBetweenRange(1337193000000, 1337797800000));​
```

This follows the code by @Stano, except that binary search is ran twice to identify the tighter bounds. It can be improved, of course.

Here's the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/EJsmy/1/

Comment: I see what you mean by identifying a larger value than given value and  admit I wasn't thinking outside of the box enough to see that simply linearly checking the bounds given by the searches can be done to do the clean-up. I was thinking more like `.slice(bs(min),bs(max))` which of course cannot be done. I am gonna float this answer above bergi's.

Comment: @Esailija thank you. Actually, it is possible to use slice() here too, but the problem is to identify exactly the bounds. The easiest way might be this: http://jsfiddle.net/3VR4k/

it might make sense to do it this way if the ranges are usually large

Comment: Yes you can use slice but it won't give correct results (So, you can't ) because the binary searches cannot identify exact bounds, but I have been wrong before... lol

Comment: Yes, the bound would have to be adjusted, but it is easy to show that the adjustment won't take up more than O(1) time, so the overall O(log(n)) is preserved: http://jsfiddle.net/3VR4k/4/;
P.S. sorry, my previous comment contained a link to the wrong fiddle.

Comment: I think, with your indizes you can use `dates.slice(start+1, end);` to get the correct results - `low` is the item before the range, and `high` the one after it

Comment: Regarding the updated fiddle: In my mind you have just delegated the `.push`ing to `.splice`, it's pretty much the same as the previous one.

Comment: @Bergi nope, start is the one that's lower or equal to the min. And it's taken care of when I adjust the bounds. I have to admit your solution is more elegant, though.

Comment: @Esailija using a built-in function is generally more efficient than doing the work yourself. Especially when you're working with javascript, which isn't all that efficient, unfortunately.

Comment: @Qnan yeah I am evaluating it more at a conceptual level. `.push` and loops tend to be really fast in chrome though, much faster than `[].slice.call` the last time I checked.

Comment: Here's the jsperf of all posted code and OP's code http://jsperf.com/filterarray/3

Comment: @Esailija that's interesting. Could you also check the last version of mine (http://jsfiddle.net/3VR4k/4/)? I'm surprised `sliceRange()` outperforms the rest so.

Comment: @Esailija of course, the relevance of the benchmark depends on the typical size of the range on is interested in. In the benchmark, a large range is used, almost a half of the whole interval in question, so the way one identifies the boundaries is likely to matter much less than the way the identified range is copied.

Comment: the `.splice` one is really good, there must be some kind of hidden optimization going on. I mean 1.4 million vs 531 compared to bergi's code. I don't think the jsperf can be trusted at all :D

Comment: it won't be so drastic if the query range is smaller, say (13412,13512)

Answer (score 0):

```
  function getDatesBetweenRange(min,max)
    {   
      var subArray = dates.slice(0,dates.length-1);

      for(var iCntr=0;iCntr<dates.length;iCntr++)
       {
       if(!(dates[iCntr] >=min && dates[iCntr] <=max))
          {
             subArray.splice(iCntr,1); 
          }
        }
       return subArray; 
   }
```

Comment: This will alter original `dates` array as well.

Comment: This will not work. It will remove 1 element at iCntr position

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov:- Is it fine now??

Comment: @AshwinPrabhu: tried in try it editor, and its working(w3school)

Comment: @Anonymous, no. You're doing shallow copy and by definition of question there could be many elements in original array. This considerably decrease performance.